# Spring configuration not having any effect after Boot 3 / Spring 6 migration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

It seems some of my configuration classes are no longer having any effect after migrating to Boot 3 /Spring 6:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ClientSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/any-endpoint").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `@Configuration` has been consistently removed from all `@Enable*` annotations now, and the docs are quite simple on how to proceed:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#add-configuration-annotation

> In 6.0, @Configuration is removed from @EnableWebSecurity, @EnableMethodSecurity, @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, and @EnableGlobalAuthentication.
>
> To prepare for this, wherever you are using one of these annotations, you may need to add @Configuration.

Also, as a side note, the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is now replaced by `@EnableMethodSecurity`. And with this, the `prePostEnabled` attribute is set to `true` by default, so you can remove it from the annotation with the new version.

So, in this case, we would need to change the implementations as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ClientSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/any-endpoint").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```